# Why, if ever, is it wrong to say "I hope it's not much of a trouble/hassle on your part"?

Tags: grammar, articles, grammaticality, idioms, definite-article

I read on one grammar website that the quoted sentence above was wrong, but the forum didn't provide any reason as to why that was so. One person on that website just said that a more acceptable construction was one without "of a."

I came across this sentence on [usingenglish.com/forum/threads/](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/it%E2%80%99s-not-too-much-trouble-of-a-trouble.249661/)… The last post on that thread was made over five years ago, so the thread is probably inactive.

Comment: I think this is a regional thing. I've heard "of a" used like this mainly by Americans in colloquial speech. We wouldn't use "of a" in these sentences here in the UK.  I think it may also be considered non-standard even in American English. Try this instead "I hope it's not too much trouble/hassle".  You also don't need "on your part" << this is completely redundant.

Comment: I don't think the cited instance of ***on your part*** is in common use, or has a clear universally understood meaning. It's certainly not a standard variation on ***For my part*** - meaning ***In my opinion / From my perspective / As far as I'm concerned / Speaking for myself / Personally / ...*** Better to just say *I hope it's not too much trouble **for you.*** Or don't bother with ***for you*** at all, since in practice it adds nothing to the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I see no particular reason to include "of a", but also no particular reason to condemn it.

Dictionaries cite "Too much of a {something}" as an idiomatic phrase
[macmillian](https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/too-much-of-a-something-to-do-something) You would need a countable noun for the "something".  Trouble, in the sense you are using it, is properly an uncountable noun. So "If it's not too much trouble" works fine.

But the idiom will interfere and influence speakers to insert the words "of a", especially in natural speech. treating "a trouble" as a countable noun, which causes no problems of understanding. It is very natural, especially in casual spoken English, for additional words to be inserted.

So the sentence, as quoted, is grammatical, fairly idiomatic, and will naturally be produced by native English speakers. But the form without "of a" is better and more correct.

Comment: I often hear Americans add "of a" much more frequently than we would use this construction here in the UK.  For example "It's not that big of a deal", whereas in the UK we'd say "It's not that big a deal".  I would say this is a dialect thing - a normal variation, neither wrong nor right.  However, having said that, don't think it's actually considered standard in American English either, and should probably be avoided in formal writing.